# Profiler TextData output is null

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I am doing a trace on a database and dumping the trace realtime into a table.

The reason I'm doing a trace is I want to see all the queries that are being executed against the database.

```
+-----------+------------+----------+------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----+-------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
| RowNumber | EventClass | TextData |       ApplicationName        | NTUserName | LoginName | CPU | Reads | Writes | Duration  | ClientProcessID | SPID |        StartTime        |         EndTime         | BinaryData |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----+-------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
|     13073 |         15 | NULL     | .Net SqlClient Data Provider | NULL       | reviewer  |   0 |  2172 |      0 | 439776000 |            5096 |  104 | 2012-12-14 12:54:22.893 | 2012-12-14 13:01:42.670 | NULL       |
|     13057 |         15 | NULL     | .Net SqlClient Data Provider | NULL       | reviewer  |   0 |  3198 |      4 | 436033000 |            4424 |  158 | 2012-12-14 12:52:50.457 | 2012-12-14 13:00:06.490 | NULL       |
|     10372 |         15 | NULL     | .Net SqlClient Data Provider | NULL       | reviewer  |   0 |  2124 |      0 | 400456000 |            2664 |  200 | 2012-12-14 12:48:12.347 | 2012-12-14 12:54:52.803 | NULL       |
|      4498 |         15 | NULL     | .Net SqlClient Data Provider | NULL       | reviewer  |   0 |  2099 |      0 | 399923000 |            3432 |  128 | 2012-12-14 12:06:10.140 | 2012-12-14 12:12:50.063 | NULL       |
|      8288 |         15 | NULL     | .Net SqlClient Data Provider | NULL       | reviewer  |   0 |  2525 |      2 | 399730000 |            2664 |  194 | 2012-12-14 12:38:46.863 | 2012-12-14 12:45:26.593 | NULL       |
+-----------+------------+----------+------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----+-------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
```

I'm grabbing the rows where the `duration` is highest:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [RowNumber]
      ,[EventClass]
      ,[TextData]
      ,[ApplicationName]
      ,[NTUserName]
      ,[LoginName]
      ,[CPU]
      ,[Reads]
      ,[Writes]
      ,[Duration]
      ,[ClientProcessID]
      ,[SPID]
      ,[StartTime]
      ,[EndTime]
      ,[BinaryData]
  FROM [salesdwh_testing].[dbo].[mytrace]
  order by duration desc
```

**Why is the TextData null?**

Please note that not all TextData is null, but it looks like these top 1000 are!

Answer (score 12):

EventClass 15 is "Audit Logout" there's no TextData to associate with that. It's simply the connection closing. TextData would only be associated with events like "SQL:StmtStarting", etc...

See here for more info: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/11/09/Map-SQL-Server-Profiler-EventClass-ID-to-its-name-in.aspx

From comments: The duration it shows in the log is the total connection duration.

Comment: why does logging out take so long? why is the duration so high?

Comment: The duration it shows is for the total connection duration.